# Перезапускается php скрипт каждые 40 секунд

Tags: php, apache, ispmanager

Написал скрипт который выполняется очень долго, прописал настройки для увеличения времени работы скрипта. Но скрипт стал перезапускаться каждые 40 секунд. В логах была ошибка

> mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds

. Поискал решение, везде пишут надо прописать **IPCCommTimeout** в

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

Прописал. Ошибка исчезла, но скрипт так же перезапускается. Установлена ISP панель, сервер Centos версия php 7.2.8 Подскажите что еще нужно прописать что бы проблема ушла.

Сам скрипт представляет собой телеграм бота, который чекает некоторые данные, в момент начала операции бот присылает сообщение о ее начале. Но бот присылает это сообщение например 4 раза с периодичностью около 40-60 секунд, и потом в конце так же 4 раза отдает ответ, проведенной операции.

На локальном сервере такой проблемы не было, там все работало четко, без ошибок и повторов.

Comment: Скрипт телеграм бота взаимодействует с браузером? Если вы используете браузер всего лишь для запуска скрипта, может следует запускать из консоли? В консоли нет таймаута. А если отсоединить запущенный процесс от сессии консоли, скрипт будет работать вечно (или пока что-то не упадет)

Comment: @TotalPusher бот написан на PHP работает через web hook т.е сам сервер телеграмм ему отправляет ответ. Я отправляю команду, клиент принимает, передает на сервер телеграмм, а тот в свою очередь присылает запрос на мой сервер, где скрипт обрабатывает его.  В общем если подробнее, бот принимает список FTP доступов, чекает их на валидность. И заносит валидные в базу данных. Время соединения с базой я увеличил, время работы скрипта тоже. На локалке нет ошибок, на реальном сервере эта ошибка. Причем если не прописывать IPCCommTimeout присылает больше повторов.

Comment: @TotalPusher а ошибку я вижу в логах PHP, в начале думал может глючит сам телеграмм, присылает кучу запросов одинаковых, но по логам запросов, запрос всего 1. В логах же, с периодичностью в 40 секунд появляется новая запись, с ошибкой указаной выше. И так они приходят бесконечно, не успевая отработать. Если же прописать настройку то всего несколько раз, но и ответ тоже потом приходит несколько раз.

Comment: [Fri Aug 17 02:17:11.406494 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1331] [client 149.154.167.213:53409] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
[Fri Aug 17 02:17:11.406578 2018] [core:error] [pid 1331] [client 149.154.167.213:53409] End of script output before headers: hook.php
такие логи, повторяется до бесконечности, пока не отключишь

Comment: `но по логам запросов, запрос всего 1` - вот это загадка! Я думаю, нужно нарисовать всю схему, какие веб-серверы стоят перед PHP. Есть/нет SSL. Посмотреть и выложить ВСЕ логи - начиная от первого веб-сервера, кончая последним. В PHP для уверенности я бы тоже в начале прописал `syslog(LOG_WARNING, 'скрипт запущен');`. Потом разбираться с хронологией. И `register_tick_function` "я жив". Как-то так

Comment: @TotalPusher но раз скрипт перезапускает разв 40 секунд, это ограничение где то прописано. Но по известным мне путям, вообще не было настроек. Те которые добавил как бы работают, но видимо есть где то еще. Я с таким ни когда не сталкивался, так как не было задачи проверять валидность FTP доступов через PHP

Comment: `перезапускает разв 40 секунд, это ограничение где то прописано`. Вот и ищите как. Я думаю, дергает телеграм. Тщательно проверьте. Смотрите логи. Пишите в сислог. Вы не показали ни конфиги, ни логи, ни скрипт. В такой ситуации помочь вам крайне проблематично.